# Packaging without setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pypi

Did anybody try to create tools that create Python source distributions (`sdist`) without `setup.py`? Does Python allow that? Is that at all possible? Or `setup.py` is an obligatory part of any isntallable Python archive hosted on PyPI? If yes, then where is a PEP for that format?

Answer (score 2):

A Python package is just a bunch of Python files in a folder, [possibly](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) with an `__init__.py` file as well.  It might also have subpackages, which are just packages within packages.

Generally, `setup.py` is not included in any such package.

Comment: And how can I install such package without `setup.py`? `pip` fails with `Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /temp/pip-e1wuf9-build`

Comment: `pip` does not take Python packages as inputs, it produces them as outputs.  It takes *distributions* as inputs.  A distribution will necessarily involve a `setup.py` file, because that's how `pip` knows what to do.  If you don't want to have a `setup.py` file, you have to do everything by hand.  That includes getting the package into one of the directories listed in `sys.path`.  Once you've done that, the package can be imported.

Comment: I meant `distribution` as the one that you pull from PyPI, not `package` as multi-file Python module. Edited my question.